# perl output messed up in fedora, ubuntu

Tags: linux, perl, terminal, fedora-25

I wrote a perl script for mapping two data sets. When I run the program using the Linux terminal, the output is messed up. It seems like the output is overlapping. I am using Fedora 25. I have tried the code on Windows and it works fine.

Same problem is there on Ubuntu as well.

DESIRED:

ADAM 123 JOHN 321

TOM 473 BENTLY 564

and so on....

OUTPUT that i am getting:

ADAM 123N 321

TOM 473TLY 564

and so on......

I have tested the code on Windows and it works perfectly fine. Though the same problem remains on Ubuntu 16.04 lts.

please help.

**code:**

```
use warnings;

open F, "friendship_network_wo_weights1.txt", or die;
open G, "username_gender_1.txt", or die;

while (<G>){
    chomp $_;
    my @a = split /\t/, $_;
    $list{$a[0]} = $a[1];
}
close G;

while (<F>){
    chomp $_;
    my @b = split /\t/, $_;
    if ((exists $list{$b[0]}) && (exists $list{$b[1]})){
        $get =  "$b[0]\t${list{$b[0]}}\t$b[1]\t${list{$b[1]}}\n";
        $get =~ s/\r//g;
        print "$get";
    }
}

close F;
```

Comment: Showing us the code would help...

Comment: You have probably some control characters in the output, maybe passed through from the input. Redirect the output into a file and look at this file with some editor displaying these characters (like vim) or do a hexdump or xxd.

Comment: Parts of Windows line endings, CR or `\r`,  make the cursor go left on *nix, but don't create a new line.

Comment: after redirecting the output to a file, there are multiple \s in the output file.

Comment: "after redirecting the output to a file, I found out that there are multiple \s coming up at every alternate line (possibly when i use \n with print command)"

Comment: use warnings;

open F, "friendship_network_wo_weights1.txt", or die;
open G, "username_gender_1.txt", or die;

while (<G>){
 chomp $_;
 my @a = split /\t/, $_;
 $list{$a[0]} = $a[1];
}
close G;

while (<F>){
 chomp $_;
 my @b = split /\t/, $_;
 if ((exists $list{$b[0]}) && (exists $list{$b[1]})){
  print  "$b[0]\t${list{$b[0]}}\t$b[1]\t${list{$b[1]}}\n";
 }
}

close F;

Comment: @HarpreetSingh [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42056751/edit) and add the code, please.

Comment: after checking it in vim, there is an unwanted addintion of "^M" in the output, where there is overlap.
ADAM    123^M   JOHN     321
and so on

Comment: partial solution found
before printing the output, I substituted \r with nothing, the code now works fine, but this solution is not permanent. Looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: My crystal ball says your input files are in DOS/Windows format with CRLF line endings.

Comment: i have added the code, have a look and please help, I found out the problem. there are \r or ^M appearing out of no where (reason for messed up output), i can substitute it every time before printing but i will not solve the purpose. Thank you

Comment: i wrote this code in gedit on fedora

Comment: Missing `use strict;`. Use lexical variables, not bareword filehandles. Use 3-arg `open`, not 2-arg `open`. Include the filename and `$!` in the error message. `%list` and `$get` are undeclared (implicitly global).

Comment: The "permanent solution" is to fix your txt files.

Comment: i have made all the changes as pointed out by you, but the problem still resists, \r or ^M is still showing up, (i wrote this code in gedit on fedora)

Comment: @melpomene If it's just a one-off, yeah, run it through `dos2unix`. In a cross-platform environment, that's not such a good idea. If the text files are being handed around between machines that's a lot of converting back and forth. If the files are large, or they update often, or they're passed around often, that can get computationally and administratively expensive, and eventually someone will forget. It's better to be tolerant than deal with all that accounting and rewriting.

Comment: @Schwern True, if the files move around, it's better to adapt the code. I was assuming the files would be "static".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on Windows the newline is `\r\n`. On everything else it's `\n`. Assuming these files were created on Windows, when you read them on Unix each line will still have a trailing `\r` after the `chomp`.

`\r` is the "carriage return" character. It's like on an old typewriter how you had to move the whole typehead back to the left side at the end of a line, computer displays used to be [fancy typewriters called Teleprinters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter). When you print it, the cursor moves back to the beginning of the line. Anything you print after that gets overwritten. Here's a simple example.

```
print "foo\rbar\r\n";
```

What you'll see is `bar`. This is because it prints...

1. `foo`
2. `\r` sends the cursor back to the start of the line
3. `bar` overwrites `foo`
4. `\r` sends the cursor back to the start of the line
5. `\n` goes to the start of the next line (doesn't matter where the cursor is)

`chomp` will only remove whatever is in `$/` off the end of the string. On Unix that's `\n`. On Windows it's `\r\n`.

There's a number of ways to solve this. One of the safest is to manually remove newlines of both types with a regex.

```
# \015 is octal character 015 which is carriage return.
# \012 is octal character 012 which is newline
$line =~ s{\015?\012$}{};
```

That says to remove maybe a `\r` and definitely a `\n` at the end of the line.

Comment: Alternatively: `s/\R\z//`

Comment: The default value of `$/` is always `\n`, never `\r\n`.

Comment: If you want to remove `\r`, why write `\015`? Those are not (always) the same thing.

Comment: thanks for the answer!!!! i wrote the script in gedit on fedora. And is there a way to permanently fix this issue?

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Dude, fix your .txt files. It doesn't matter what editor you wrote the script in.

Comment: @melpomene Exactly, they're not always the same thing. It's more a habit I got into for `\n`; I can never remember how that works cross-platform so `\012` to be safe. I think we can safely assume they're not gonna encounter EBCDIC files, and VMS does its own thing to translate records into lines. As for `$/` it's documented to be "newline" which is ambiguous. And IO in Windows Perl has a layer of newline translation that I can never remember how it works... so I like to be explicit. My head is full of 5.6 madness. But `\R` is neat, I didn't know about that. That's probably the best solution.

Comment: How did you get two dowvnotes for this?

Comment: "newline" is simply `\n`. That's the whole point: `\n` is the portable newline abstraction ... Well, it depends in which direction you want to be portable: The same code working with native text files on many platforms, or code running on a single platform but processing text files in many different formats.

Comment: @simbabque I guess because I didn't get the complexities of cross-platform newline handling in Perl exactly right?

Comment: @melpomene Which is why I recommend just using `/\015?\012\z/` and not trying to remember how that all works. I'll start recommending `/\R\z/`.

Comment: @Schwern That's awful advice. Figure out which problem you want to solve (e.g. choose between processing native files everywhere and processing Windows text files on any platform), then write code for it. This `\015?\012\z` thing seems too much like cargo culting. And it's not like this is all arcane Perl subtleties: C and C++ use exactly the same text processing model (which is where Perl got it from, of course).

Comment: @melpomene Using C and C++ as examples of languages which are not arcane and subtle... oh boy. Yes, Perl is a surprisingly thin wrapper around C; this explains a lot of its sins. Most Perl people have never used C nor C++, assuming they have explains a lot more Perl sins. Anyhow, the question was about processing text files of unknown origin. `/\015?\012\z/` and `/\R\z/` work fine. Explaining the odd behavior is the important thing, the OP has apparently never encountered this before and doesn't need a treatise on Perl newline handling. At this point, you should write up your own answer.